# JS que bloquea abrir un enlace

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Me gustaría saber por qué se prioriza la ejecución de un js al clickar en un botón que a su vez tiene un enlace  definido.
Es decir, en el menú de navegación, cuando se clicka en un elemento, se despliega todas las opciones agrupadas en él (esta acción la ejecuta el js). Sin embargo, este mismo elemento también debería abrir una nueva ventana ya que tiene implementado un enlace  ¿Por qué ocurre esto y no se abre este enlace?

El ejemplo concreto es con el menú de navegación en versión mobile.
La página de categoría (imaginemos zapatos), al clickarse de despliegan todas las opciones (zapatos blancos y zapatos negros). Este elemento contiene un enlace  que debería abrirse cuando se clicka en el elemento, sin embargo, la unico que ocurre es que se despliegan todas las subcategorias.

Os dejo el código:

```
    <li role="presentation">

<img class="mobile" src="/media/catalog/category/dfgdfgdf.jpg">

<a href="https://URL-de-categoria.html" aria-haspopup="true" role="menuitem">
<span> Zapatos </span></a>

<ul role="menu" aria-expanded="true" style="display: block; top: 98.3438px; left: 0px;">

<li role="presentation">
<a href="https://URL-subcategoria.html" role="menuitem">
<span>Zapatos blancos</span>
</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
<a href="https://URL-de-subcategoria2.html">
<span>Zapatos negros</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Si puedes añadir un [mcve] sería de gran ayuda para comprender que es lo que te está ocurriendo, como esta ahora tu pregunta solo podemos dar opiniones y teorías, para una respuesta correcta necesitamos mas información

Comment: Si entiendo bien, un botón: ¿`<button>`? , que a su vez tiene un enlace ¿`href`?. Si es eso, muy mal. Los elementos de tipo `<button>` no implementan el atributo `href`, y aunque se lo pongas no hará lo mismo que un elemento `anchor` (`<a>`). Saludos

Answer (score -2):

Para que vayas directo al link tienes que darle click en el span según estoy viendo, es decir, a la palabra concreta Zapatos blancos/negros.
Prueba a poner el a href al li completo, te fastidiará el CSS muy probablemente, pero así harás que el contenedor completo sea el link, que es lo usual.

A parte, como consejo, si vas a hacer eso, ya que es un problema de funcionalidad, le haría un hoover para que desplegase el contenido por CSS y no por click.